# Get index of shuffled blob [blob of an image , audio etc...]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object containing array of blobs (represented as strings here!) and a `pictureIndex` like this:

```
const data = {
    pictures: ['blob1','blob2','blob3'],
    pictureIndex: 0 
}

shuffleArray(data.pictures);
```

Note: `pictureIndex` is the index of `'blob1'`

I want to shuffle the blobs inside pictures array to have a new random arrangement of the blobs but I want to get the index of `blob1` at the final shuffled array. So if shuffled data is this:

```
 ['blob2','blob3','blob1']
```

I want to return **2** as `pictureIndex` of 'blob1'...

So far I can shuffle the pictures easily like this without any idea how to modify the `pictureIndex`:

```js
const data = {
    pictures: ['blob1','blob2','blob3'],
    pictureIndex: 0 
}


shuffleArray(data.pictures);

function shuffleArray(array) {
    let currentIndex = array.length,  randomIndex;
    while (0 !== currentIndex) {
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex--;
        [array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex]] = [array[randomIndex], array[currentIndex]];
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: You can make an array of size equals to `data.pictures` and add consecutive numbers to it like `[0,1,2,3,......]`.  And then suffle the new array. Then you can use `newArray.indexOf(data.pictures.indexOf(blob1))` to keep track of that picture index.

Comment: May be this will help you to save computing resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to make the shuffle function, accept the full object, then return the full object with the shuffled array and updated index.

It would then save you from needing to find the index again from the shuffled array.

```js
let data = {
  pictures: ['blob1', 'blob2', 'blob3'],
  pictureIndex: 0
}

data = shufflePictures(data);

console.log(data)

function shufflePictures(data) {
  let currentIndex = data.pictures.length,
    randomIndex;
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex--;
    [data.pictures[currentIndex], data.pictures[randomIndex]] = [data.pictures[randomIndex], data.pictures[currentIndex]];
    if (randomIndex === data.pictureIndex) {
      data.pictureIndex = currentIndex
    }
  }
  return data
}
```